# what does "an early start" mean here?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

Born in London on April 3, 1934, world-renowned primatologist Jane Goodall **got an early start** on animal study, spending much of her childhood observing animals that lived right in the backyard of her house.

Would you show me in a readily way what the bold part means? although I have studied what "early" means.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that *Got an early start* signifies  that Jane Goodall started her study during her younger years, when she was a child.

Comment: Not necessarily as a child; this expression can also mean _early in one's **career**._

Comment: @J.R.- perhaps not in general, but in this case it definitely means *as a child*:  "...spending much of her childhood observing animals..."